# warning facesmessage(s) have been enqueued but may not have been displayed

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jboss7.x

i have a form with inputs validation as follows:

```
<h:form id="insurance-form" rendered = "#{(param['insSaved']=='editable')}">
    <div id="insurance-info">
        <ul id="form-labels" style="text-align:left;">
            <li>Insurance Company&nbsp;</li>
            <li>Policy Number&nbsp;</li>
            <li>Coverage Amount&nbsp;</li>
            <li>Agent's Phone Number&nbsp;</li>
            <li>Agent's Email&nbsp;</li>
        </ul>

        <ul>
            <li>
                <h:inputText value="#{residenceBeans.insuranceCompany}" id="insurance-company" required="true" requiredMessage="company is required"/>
                <h:message for="insurance-company" styleClass="validation-error-msg insuarnce-validation"/>
            </li>

            <li>
                <h:inputText value="#{residenceBeans.policyNumber}" id="insurance-policy" required="true" requiredMessage="number is required"/>
                <h:message for="insurance-policy" styleClass="validation-error-msg insuarnce-validation"/>
            </li>

            <li>
                <h:inputText value="#{residenceBeans.coverageAmount}" id="insurance-amount" required="true" requiredMessage="coverage amount is required"/>
                <h:message for="insurance-amount" styleClass="validation-error-msg insuarnce-validation"/>
            </li>

            <li>
                <h:inputText value="#{residenceBeans.agentPhone}" id="insurance-phone" required="true" requiredMessage="phone is required"/>
                <h:message for="insurance-phone" styleClass="validation-error-msg  insuarnce-validation"/>
            </li>

            <li>
                <h:inputText value="#{residenceBeans.agentMail}" id="insurance-mail" required="true" requiredMessage="email is required">
                    <f:validator validatorId="emailValidator"/>
                </h:inputText>
                <h:message for="insurance-mail" styleClass="validation-error-msg insuarnce-validation"/>
            </li>
        </ul>                                       

        <h:commandLink value="SAVE POLICY INFORMATION" action="#{residenceBeans.saveInsuranceInfo}"  styleClass="insurance-link-container">
            <f:param name="insSaved" value="saved"/>
        </h:commandLink>
    </div>
</h:form>
```

when leaving fields empty and submitting the form i am expecting the validation messages to be displayed, but instead i am getting the following warning:

```
21:20:47,671 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.renderkit] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-3) WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been displayed
sourceId=insurance-form:insurance-company[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(company is required), detail=(company is required)]
sourceId=insurance-form:insurance-policy[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(number is required), detail=(number is required)]
sourceId=insurance-form:insurance-amount[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(coverage amount is required), detail=(coverage amount is required)]
sourceId=insurance-form:insurance-phone[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(phone is required), detail=(phone is required)]
sourceId=insurance-form:insurance-mail[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(email is required), detail=(email is required)]
```

please advise how to fix that.

Comment: Have you changed the default naming container separator character from `:` to `-`? By the way, the form's `rendered` attribute doesn't match the `f:param` value, so the whole form wouldn't have been rendered at all after submitting. Isn't that just the cause of your concrete problem? But wouldn't it be obvious that it's the whole form which didn't show up and not only the messages?

Comment: @BalusC, no i have not changed the separator the id's looks like: insurance-form:insurance-company as expected. what do you advise ?

Comment: @BalusC, so i should use the rendered attribute on the inputs instead ?

Comment: But the code which you've so far would hide the entire `<h:form>` altogether once it's been submitted, including all the child `<h:message>` components, because the `<h:form rendered>` would evaluate to `false`. Therefore the messages are indeed never displayed, so the warning message in the logs is fully expected. Is this your *real* code or a careless oversimplification? Please re-read the previous comment once again.

Comment: @BalusC, this is a code for another person which i am working on, after clicking on the button it hides the form and display the input values as labels, i guess it shouldn't hide the form in case of validation errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The messages are not been displayed because the whole form is not been rendered at all on postback. You instructed the form to be rendered only when the request parameter of `insSaved` has a value of `editable`. However, in the submit button it's been changed to `saved`, so the form is basically never rendered on postback and the enclosed messages thus also not. This is fully expected behaviour given the way how the code is set up.

If you'd like to show the form in case of a validation error on postback anyway, then you'd need to alter its `rendered` attribute accordingly. Replace

```
<h:form id="insurance-form" rendered="#{(param['insSaved']=='editable')}">
```

by

```
<h:form id="insurance-form" rendered="#{(facesContext.postback and facesContext.validationFailed) or (param['insSaved'] == 'editable')}">
```

Answer (score -2):

I experienced this issue, the response is to delete the primefaces library and then add again to the libraries list.